# Laravel query error

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

laravel return this error on execute this line:

```
    $select = trim($request->select);
    $where = trim($request->where);
    $d = trim($request->d);
    $order = trim(stripslashes($request->order));
    $limit = isSet($request->limit) ? " LIMIT ".trim($request->limit) : '';
    $forUser = trim(stripslashes($request->userId));
    $campaignId = trim(stripslashes($request->campaignId));
    $userRole = trim(stripslashes($request->userRole));

$events = DB::select('SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, ?) selector FROM events WHERE DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, ?) = ? AND campaignId = ? ORDER BY ? ASC ?', [$select, $where, $d, $campaignId, $order, $limit])->get();
```

Error:

> [2018-05-21 19:09:22] local.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\spotlike_laravel\trunk\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection.php:77

Any ideas? :(

Comment: Do you know if all those variables that you are passing have some data? For debugging reason, I will try to execute the SQL outside of Laravel if I could so you can isolate the problem.

Comment: You seem to miss a `LIMIT` keyword in your query when I look at your variables and the question marks in the query.

Comment: I found the query, but when I run it in phpmyadmin it does not return errors, the query look like this:

SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, "%Y-%c-%e") selector FROM events WHERE DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, "%Y-%c") = "2018-5" AND campaignId = "194" ORDER BY timestamp, id ASC

Comment: Posted this as an answer, but didn't work! Will post as a comment to potentially help someone in the future:

Try putting the timestamp field name in backticks. IIRC timestamp is a reserved word.

Also, as a side note, I don't know if you can use bound parameters for the order by and limit parameters, because PDO will wrap the parameter values in quotes, resulting in something like:

`ORDER BY 'some_field' ASC 'LIMIT 30'`

Comment: To get the query and bindings, try this:
`$events = DB::select('SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, ?) selector FROM events WHERE DATE_FORMAT(timestamp, ?) = ? AND campaignId = ? ORDER BY ? ASC ?', [$select, $where, $d, $campaignId, $order, $limit]); dd($event->toSql(), $event->getBindings());` That will `dd` the query and the parameters that are passed. Might shed a little bit more light on the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved, the variable "$limit" was empty, then on the concatenate of $limit generate a blank space on the query. Thanks darol and Phil!